# Can I improve grunt watch speed?

Tags: php, less, grunt-contrib-watch

I've been using PHP storm for my code editing and have been using grunt in the terminal. While running watch, mainly the edits I've been making are to my less files and in the past it would take 2-3 seconds to run and minify. But for an unknown reason to me, it now takes 30-50 seconds for watch to finish.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this may be happening? Is there something I can do in the grunt file or elsewhere to speed it up again?